# Add multiple external oidc provides to Duende Identity Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, single-sign-on, identityserver4, duende-identity-server

I passed through the tutorial:
https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/quickstarts/2_interactive/

And in adittional I tried to add another instance of the Identity Server as another external Identity Provider. After this it just stops working right after starting. No errors, no warnings...

Each one works separately.

Whether who faced it?

Here is how I registered several Identity Providers:

```
        builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
         .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", "Demo IdentityServer", options =>
         {
             options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
             options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;
             options.SaveTokens = true;

             options.Authority = "https://demo.duendesoftware.com";
             options.ClientId = "interactive.confidential";
             options.ClientSecret = "secret";
             options.ResponseType = "code";

             options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
             {
                 NameClaimType = "name",
                 RoleClaimType = "role"
             };

         })
         .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", "My IdentityServer", options =>
         {
             options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
             options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;
             options.SaveTokens = true;

             options.Authority = "https://localhost:5004";
             options.ClientId = "myprovider";
             options.ClientSecret = "secret";
             options.ResponseType = "code";

             options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
             {
                 NameClaimType = "name",
                 RoleClaimType = "role"
             };

         });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that both handlers are listening on the same callback URLs (the URL's IdentityServer sends requests to the client)

by default they are set to

```
CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-oidc");
SignedOutCallbackPath = new PathString("/signout-callback-oidc");
RemoteSignOutPath = new PathString("/signout-oidc");
```

You need to set them to different paths in each handler.

Also, the schema name should be different "oidc"

But in general, I think it's a bad idea to have your client trust two different Identity providers, I think it's better to only have it trust one.

The alternative is to have your own Identity provider locally, that then  trusts various external providers, like this:

[image]

Generally, your complexity will be reduced if every service only has to trust one provider. Especially, for the APIs using JwtBearer, they prefer to only have one trusted provider.

Comment: I don't understand why different oidc declarations can't works with the same oidc handler. So what you are said means that there is no way to add several Sotial Networks IDPs using oidc.? And the only way that can be provided on ASP.NET is to use predefine handlers for this?

Comment: You can have multiple handlers in your client, but you need to understand where they collide and they need to have different schema names and different paths.

The alternative is to use federated identity, as shown in my updated answer.

Comment: Got it! I thinked that Schema 'oidc' and pathes are reserved names for OpenID Connect, but it's just a values to distinguish different schemas. Thanks.

Comment: that diagram is exactly what I'm after @ToreNestenius, but I'm struggling to find any information on how to configure it that way... any suggestions?

Comment: see the link here https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/ui/federation/