# How to integrate multiple Identity Providers with Identity Server 4, while also using Cookies and JWT auth

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, identityserver4

**Goal**

I'm trying to implement the scenario described by @ToreNestenius in the diagram [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73203165/1414258).
[image: Identity Server as intermediary between Client and External Identity Providers]

**Configuration**

I have multiple API services, an instance of Identity Server 4, and a React SPA front end.

I have a client configured on my IS4 for the react SPA, which is allowed the following scopes { openid, profile, email, offline_access, myApi1, myApi2 }

I have OIDC configured for the react application, which is working great.

My APIs have multiple auth schemes configured, Cookies and JWTs, and are configured with Swagger for developers (using the same client as React), which uses the OpenApiOAuthFlow and is working great.

My APIs and my ID server all user the following auth setup:

```
const string AUTH_SCHEME = "JWT_OR_COOKIE";
const string BEARER = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
const string COOKIE = "Cookies";
const string OIDC = "oidc";
const string COOKIE_NAME = "myapp.identity";

var localAuthority = "https://localhost:10000";

services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(
    options => 
    {
        options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromDays(90);
    });

services
    // JWT + Cookie auth adapted from Rick Strahl's approach @ https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2022/Mar/29/Combining-Bearer-Token-and-Cookie-Auth-in-ASPNET
    .AddAuthentication(
        options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = AUTH_SCHEME;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = AUTH_SCHEME;
        })
    .AddJwtBearer(BEARER,
        options =>
        {
            options.Authority = localAuthority;
            options.ForwardChallenge = BEARER;

            // Taken from: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/575339/jwt-with-authorization-client-side.html
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = localAuthority,

                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = "MyResourceName",

                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            };
        })
    .AddCookie(COOKIE,
        options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = COOKIE_NAME;
            options.ForwardChallenge = OIDC;
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
        })
    .AddOpenIdConnect(OIDC,
        options =>
        {
            options.Authority = authority;
            options.ClientId = client.ClientId;
            options.ClientSecret = client.ClientSecret;
            options.ResponseType = "code";
            options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";

            options.Scope.Clear();
            foreach (var scope in client.AllowedScopes) // { openid, profile, email, offline_access, myApi1, myApi2 }
                options.Scope.Add(scope);
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            options.SaveTokens = true;
        })
    .AddPolicyScheme(AUTH_SCHEME, AUTH_SCHEME,
        options => options.ForwardDefaultSelector =
            context =>
            {
                string auth = context.Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(auth) && auth.StartsWith(BEARER))
                    return BEARER;
                return COOKIE;
            });
```

All of that has been working great.

**Where the problem begins**

Now I'm trying to add a second OpenIdConnect scheme for an external ID provider.

I have registered an application with Azure, with a redirect URL of `https://localhost:10000/signin-microsoft`, which is my locally hosted URL.

[image: My registration details in Azure showing the application redirect URL and Access Tokens and ID Token flows enabled]

I've tried adapting from [damienbod](https://damienbod.com/2017/07/11/adding-an-external-microsoft-login-to-identityserver4/)'s approach - by adding the following OIDC configuration to my IS4 service collection:

```
var azureAuthority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/";

services
// https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/signin_external_providers.html#state-url-length-and-isecuredataformat
.AddOidcStateDataFormatterCache()
.AddOpenIdConnect("AzureAD", "AzureAD",
    options =>
    {
        options.Authority = azureAuthority;
        options.ClientId = "MY_AZURE_REGISTERED_APPLICATION_CLIENT_GUID";
        options.ClientSecret = "MY_AZURE_REGISTERED_APPLICATION_SECRET_VALUE";
        options.ResponseType = "code";
        options.CallbackPath = "/signin-microsoft";

        options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
        options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;
        options.RemoteAuthenticationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);

        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.Scope.Add("email");
        options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false, // multi tenant => means all tenants can use this
            NameClaimType = "name",
        };
        options.Prompt = "login"; // login, consent select_account
    })
```

When I go to log in and use the external Azure provider, it successfully redirects me and I'm able to log in and get redirected back to my callback.

I'm using a challenge and callback adapted from damienbod's code linked above, which look like:

ChallengeModel:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class ChallengeModel : PageModel
{
    readonly IIdentityServerInteractionService _interactionService;
    public ChallengeModel(IIdentityServerInteractionService interactionService) =>
        _interactionService = interactionService;

    public IActionResult OnGet(string scheme, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            returnUrl = "~/";

        // validate returnUrl - either it is a valid OIDC URL or back to a local page
        if (!Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) &&
            !_interactionService.IsValidReturnUrl(returnUrl))
            throw new Exception("invalid return URL"); // user might have clicked on a malicious link - should be logged

        // start challenge and roundtrip the return URL and scheme 
        var props = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = Url.Page("/externallogin/callback"),

            Items =
            {
                { "returnUrl", returnUrl },
                { "scheme", scheme },
            }
        };

        return Challenge(props, scheme);
    }
}
```

CallbackModel:

```
public class CallbackModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly UserManager<MyIdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<MyIdentityUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly IIdentityServerInteractionService _interaction;
    private readonly ILogger<CallbackModel> _logger;
    private readonly IEventService _events;

    public CallbackModel(
        IIdentityServerInteractionService interaction,
        IEventService events,
        ILogger<CallbackModel> logger,
        UserManager<MyIdentityUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<MyIdentityUser> signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _interaction = interaction;
        _logger = logger;
        _events = events;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
    {
        // read external identity from the temporary cookie
        var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
        if (result?.Succeeded != true)
            throw new Exception("External authentication error");

        var externalUser = result.Principal;

        if (_logger.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Debug))
        {
            var externalClaims = externalUser.Claims.Select(c => $"{c.Type}: {c.Value}");
            _logger.LogDebug("External claims: {@claims}", externalClaims);
        }

        // lookup our user and external provider info
        // try to determine the unique id of the external user (issued by the provider)
        // the most common claim type for that are the sub claim and the NameIdentifier
        // depending on the external provider, some other claim type might be used
        var userIdClaim = externalUser.FindFirst(JwtClaimTypes.Subject) ??
                          externalUser.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier) ??
                          throw new Exception("Unknown userid");

        var provider = result.Properties.Items["scheme"];
        var providerUserId = userIdClaim.Value;

        // find external user
        var user = await _userManager.FindByLoginAsync(provider, providerUserId);
        if (user == null)
        {
            // this might be where you might initiate a custom workflow for user registration
            // in this sample we don't show how that would be done, as our sample implementation
            // simply auto-provisions new external user
            user = await AutoProvisionUserAsync(provider, providerUserId, externalUser.Claims);
        }

        // this allows us to collect any additional claims or properties
        // for the specific protocols used and store them in the local auth cookie.
        // this is typically used to store data needed for signout from those protocols.
        var additionalLocalClaims = new List<Claim>();
        var localSignInProps = new AuthenticationProperties();
        CaptureExternalLoginContext(result, additionalLocalClaims, localSignInProps);

        // issue authentication cookie for user
        await _signInManager.SignInWithClaimsAsync(user, localSignInProps, additionalLocalClaims);

        // delete temporary cookie used during external authentication
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);

        // retrieve return URL
        var returnUrl = result.Properties.Items["returnUrl"] ?? "~/";

        // check if external login is in the context of an OIDC request
        var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);
        await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(provider, providerUserId, user.Id, user.UserName, true, context?.Client.ClientId));

        if (context != null && context.IsNativeClient())
            // The client is native, so this change in how to
            // return the response is for better UX for the end user.
            return this.LoadingPage(returnUrl);

        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }

    private async Task<MyIdentityUser> AutoProvisionUserAsync(string provider, string providerUserId, IEnumerable<Claim> claims)
    {
        var sub = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        var user = new MyIdentityUser
        {
            Id = sub,
            UserName = sub, // don't need a username, since the user will be using an external provider to login
        };

        // email
        var email = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == JwtClaimTypes.Email)?.Value ??
                    claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;
        if (email != null)
            user.Email = email;

        // create a list of claims that we want to transfer into our store
        var filtered = new List<Claim>();

        // user's display name
        var name = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == JwtClaimTypes.Name)?.Value ??
                   claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
        if (name != null)
            filtered.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, name));
        else
        {
            var first = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == JwtClaimTypes.GivenName)?.Value ??
                        claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.GivenName)?.Value;
            var last = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == JwtClaimTypes.FamilyName)?.Value ??
                       claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Surname)?.Value;
            if (first != null && last != null)
                filtered.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, first + " " + last));
            else if (first != null)
                filtered.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, first));
            else if (last != null)
                filtered.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, last));
        }

        var identityResult = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
        if (!identityResult.Succeeded)
            throw new Exception(identityResult.Errors.First().Description);

        if (filtered.Any())
        {
            identityResult = await _userManager.AddClaimsAsync(user, filtered);
            if (!identityResult.Succeeded)
                throw new Exception(identityResult.Errors.First().Description);
        }

        identityResult = await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, new UserLoginInfo(provider, providerUserId, provider));
        if (!identityResult.Succeeded)
            throw new Exception(identityResult.Errors.First().Description);

        return user;
    }

    // if the external login is OIDC-based, there are certain things we need to preserve to make logout work
    // this will be different for WS-Fed, SAML2p or other protocols
    private void CaptureExternalLoginContext(AuthenticateResult externalResult, List<Claim> localClaims, AuthenticationProperties localSignInProps)
    {
        // capture the idp used to login, so the session knows where the user came from
        localClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.IdentityProvider, externalResult.Properties.Items["scheme"]));

        // if the external system sent a session id claim, copy it over
        // so we can use it for single sign-out
        var sid = externalResult.Principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == JwtClaimTypes.SessionId);
        if (sid != null)
            localClaims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.SessionId, sid.Value));

        // if the external provider issued an id_token, we'll keep it for signout
        var idToken = externalResult.Properties.GetTokenValue("id_token");
        if (idToken != null)
            localSignInProps.StoreTokens(new[]
            {
                new AuthenticationToken { Name = "id_token", Value = idToken }
            });
    }
}
```

However, when my callback completes I get the following exception:

```
System.Exception: OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler: message.State is null or empty.

Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler<TOptions>.HandleRequestAsync()
IdentityServer4.Hosting.FederatedSignOut.AuthenticationRequestHandlerWrapper.HandleRequestAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpLogging.HttpLoggingMiddleware.InvokeInternal(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.Azure.AppConfiguration.AspNetCore.AzureAppConfigurationRefreshMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

My Identity server configuration is pretty standard, as follows:

```
.AddIdentity<MyIdentityUser, IdentityRole>(
    options =>
    {
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;

        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;

        options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    })
.AddTokenProvider<DataProtectorTokenProvider<MyIdentityUser>>(TokenOptions.DefaultProvider)
.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>()
.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<MyIdentityUser>>()
.AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<MyClaimsPrincipalFactory>();

services
    .Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(
        options =>
        {
            options.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
        })
    .AddLocalApiAuthentication()
    .AddAuthorization(...);

services
.AddIdentityServer(
    options =>
    {
        options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
        options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
        options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = false;
    })
.AddConfigurationStore(
    options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(dbConnectionStr, sql =>
            sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
    })
.AddOperationalStore(
    options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(dbConnectionStr, sql =>
            sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
    })
.AddProfileService<ProfileService>()
.AddSigningCert(builder.Configuration[CommonStatics.SECRET_IDENTITY_CERT]);

services
.ConfigureApplicationCookie(config => config.Cookie.Name = CommonStatics.ID_COOKIE);
```

My Application pipeline is as follows

```
if (!app.Environment.IsProduction())
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

// NOTE regarding Middleware ordering: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0
app.UseHttpLogging();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseJwtTokenMiddleware();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(...);
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute());
```

**Questions**

- The AzureAD OIDC scheme is only requesting 4 scopes from AzureAD, which makes sense because that's all the Azure registered application knows about... But how do I then get my local identity server to validate additional client scope requests, such as "myApi1", "myApi2", which the AzureAD registered application knows nothing about?

  - I have the opportunity to inject such scope claims in the callback, but how do I validate that the calling client has access to those scopes? Seems like the wrong approach.
- Why am I getting the `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler: message.State is null or empty.` message?
- Should all of my API services call .AddOpenIdConnect(...) with both my LocalIS4 and "AzureAD" schemes? Or should only the IS4 Server have the AzureAD scheme configured?
- For users that use an external provider - should I somehow note their provider in my user database?

  - E.g. if they are externally provisioned then their password should not be set, and not settable.
  - My IS4 UI shows a password reset option when the user is logged in - how should ResetPassword work with external identity providers? If I keep track of whether a user is provisioned externally, should I disable the ResetPassword and ForgotPassword functionality for them? How is this usually handled?
- Must I have ValidateIssuer as false in the TokenValidationParameters for the AzureAD scheme, as suggested by @damienbod?

**EDIT:**

I played some more and introduced another error, "Correlation Failed", so I had to add the following options to the CorrelationCookie:

```
options.CorrelationCookie = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieBuilder
{
    HttpOnly = true,
    SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.None,
    SecurePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.Always,
    IsEssential = false,
    Expiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
};
```

and that resolved the 'Correlation Failed' error.

I was also able to fix the `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler: message.State is null or empty.` error by adding the following event handlers to the OIDC connect options and it seems to have fixed everything:

```
options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
{
    OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    },
    OnRemoteFailure = context =>
    {
        if (context.Failure.Message == "OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler: message.State is null or empty.")
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/");
            context.HandleResponse();
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    },
    OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = context =>
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    },
    OnMessageReceived = context =>
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
};
```

NOTE: that the OnAuthorizationCodeReceived event is firing, and the authentication is successful, and the callback is working as expected too. After the callback, the OnMessageReceived event is firing, but the message is null and so it's not being handled nicely by the OIDC handler. As such we just ignore that specific error. You could perhaps move the context.HandleResponse into the OnMessageReceived event but I couldn't see what to look for in there.

Comment: Glad you can proceed and authenticate successfully. Answering a few of your questions: To validate additional client scope requests, you need to expose your API in the registered applications and add permissions for your APIs and then you can use the AddJwtBearer middleware to validate the access token issued by Azure AD. You can then use the Authorize attribute with the Policy parameter to require that the access token contains the required scopes. You can also use the AddIdentityServerAuthentication middleware to validate the access token issued by your local identity server.

Comment: For the API services, you should only configure the AddOpenIdConnect middleware with the AzureAD scheme on the IS4 server. The API services should use the AddJwtBearer middleware to validate the access token issued by Azure AD.


If you are using an external identity provider, you should note the provider in your user database. You can use the IdentityUser class to store the user's external provider information.